# Make a single function work for several elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, this

I'm working on an option page for my chrome extension where the user can define a key for keyboard navigation on a page.
So I added a text "input" to my popup page where the user can set the key they wants. At the moment my function detects the key, translates into key code and writes it to a hidden "span". I save the value of that "span" locally and get it in my content script to bind the key to a function.

The following code works great for me with just 1 input.

**popup.html**

```
<div id="keys-tab">
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="1" id="theKey" /><span id="response" hidden=""></span>Key 1
</div>
```

**popup.js**

```
if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", keycodes, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", keycodes);

function keycodes() {
  var tb = document.getElementById('theKey');
  var respText = document.getElementById('response');
  respText.innerHTML = '';

  function getKeyCode(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    return event.keyCode;
  }

  function resetInput() {
    tb.onkeypress = function() {
      return false;
    }
  }
  tb.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var charCode = getKeyCode(event);
    respText.innerHTML = charCode;
    tb.value = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    switch (charCode) {
      case 8:
        tb.value = "Backspace";
        break;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

But now I want to add a bunch of them so the user can define different key for different actions. My page now looks like this. And I want every "input" do the same.

**new_popup.html**

```
<div id="keys-tab">
   <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="1" id="theKey_1" /><span id="response_1" hidden=""></span>Key 1<br />
   <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="1" id="theKey_2" /><span id="response_2" hidden=""></span>Key 2<br />
   <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="1" id="theKey_3" /><span id="response_3" hidden=""></span>Key 3
</div>
```

I know I can work with "this" and I tried it by my self, but can't get it to work. I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: try using Event.target property.
Your handler receives an event as an argument, change it to `function keycodes() {` and then change the element like this: `var tb = e.target;`

Comment: `this` does not work because you attached the event to the window.
You could also attach it to each input using document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work for you, we just have to pass the number of actions in variable **actionCount** -:

---

**popup.html**

```
<div id="keys-tab">
</div>
```

**popup.js**

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
  input.type = "text";
  input.size = 10;
  input.maxlength = "text";
  input.id = "theKey_"+i;
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  span.id = "response_"+i;
  span.hidden = "";
  var text = document.createElement("SPAN");
  text.innerHTML = "Key "+(i+1);
  text.style.display = 'inline-block';
  input.appendChild(span);
  document.getElementById("keys-tab").appendChild(input);
  document.getElementById("keys-tab").appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("keys-tab").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
  if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", keycodes("theKey_"+i,"response_"+i), false);
  else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", keycodes("theKey_"+i,"response_"+i));

}
function keycodes(keyid,responseid) {
  var tb = document.getElementById(keyid);
  console.log(tb);
  var respText = document.getElementById(responseid);
  console.log(respText);
  respText.innerHTML = "";

  function getKeyCode(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    return event.keyCode;
  }
  function resetInput() {
    tb.onkeypress = function() {
      return false;
    };
  }
  tb.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var charCode = getKeyCode(event);
    respText.innerHTML = charCode;
    tb.value = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    switch (charCode) {
      case 8:
        tb.value = "Backspace";
        break;
    }
    return false;
  };
}
```